# How to open a file for reading in C?

Tags: c, gcc

There is this thing that gives me headaches in C programming when I deal with reading from files.

I do not understand the difference between these 2 methods:

```
FILE *fd;
fd=fopen(name,"r");  // "r" for reading from file, "w" for writing to file
                      //"a" to edit the file
```

fd returns NULL if the file can't be open, right?

The second method that i use is:

```
int fd;
fd=open(name,O_RDONLY);
```

fd would be -1 if an error occurs at opening the file.

Would anyone be kind enough to explain this to me?
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using fopen() allows you to use the C stdio library, which can be a lot more convenient than working directly with file descriptors. For example, there's no built-in equivalent to fprintf(...) with file descriptors.

Unless you're in need of doing low level I/O, the stdio functions serve the vast majority of applications very well. It's more convenient, and, in the normal cases, just as fast when used correctly.

Comment: So I should use the one that I am more comfortable with, right? fopen() it is then.

Comment: I think that would be a good way to go. And yes, it returns NULL on error. If it fails, you can check errno to find out why.